# AsyncController AsyncManager parameters issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm doing some tests with an Asynchronous controller and I have the following code:

```
public class AsyncSampleController : AsyncController
{

     public void IndexAsync()
      {
           Tasks tasks = new Tasks();
           //Indicates that we already started an asynchronous operation
           AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();
           //Task.Factory start new to use another thread to use our operation.
           Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
           {
                Stopwatch s1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();        
                tasks.BigOperation();
                s1.Stop();
                long data=s1.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                AsyncManager.Parameters.Add("data",data);
            });
            AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();

       }
       public ActionResult IndexCompleted(long data)
       { 
           ViewBag.ElapsedTime = data.ToString();
           return View();
       }
}
```

The issue is that the method BigOperation spends one second more or less, but I'm not getting the elapsed value stored on data parameter on IndexCompleted Action.

Comment: I'm unclear how IndexCompleted is executed--you've never referenced it anywhere.

Comment: In theory if the controller inherits from AsyncController it tries to find the actionmethod that ends with Async and Completed in order to execute the action asynchronously.

I used localhost:{port}/AsyncSample/Index and its executing fine, but the parameter data on the IndexComplete action has a 0 value.

Comment: @Jose3d can you simply it a bit and see if it works? eg remove your long operation and simply assign `AsyncManager.Parameters["data"] = data;`

Comment: @PeterRitchie IndexCompleted is called by ASP.NET when the async operation in IndexAsync is completed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't test this but you should put the `Decrement` call *inside* your anonymous task. My guess is that `Decrement` is called before the task has completed.